# Trying to connect to ftp server with a firewall proxy using ftplib python

Tags: python, ftplib

Right now, I'm connecting to the ftp in bash using

```
echo "
user $USER1 $PASS1
user $USER2 $PASS2
user $USER3 $PASS3"|ftp -n $FTPSERVER
```

I tried to handle this in python using

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(SERVER)
ftp.sendcmd("user {} {}".format(USER1, PASS1))
ftp.sendcmd("user {} {}".format(USER2, PASS2))
...
```

When I connect using bash, the output is [image: Screenshot]

However, when I try using python, the first line only gives output "331 Password: " and if I send anymore commands, it gives the error Please supply password with PASS command.
Also, I'm not sure if it's relevant but $USER2 and $PASS2 have @ in them with $PASS2 beginning with it.